# Will a magnet mount affect the performance of a radar detector?

Tags: electrical, electronics

I am in the market for a Uniden R3 radar detector but I'm not really enthused by most of the mirror mounts out there. It distracts from my line of sight to have something up on my mirror like that so I'm looking at some dash mounting options.

I am thinking of using some combination of a Proclip and a magnet mount for the R3. Does anyone know if having a magnet directly below the radar detector will affect it's performance? Or cause interference in some way?

Comment: I don't know for *sure*, but I do have a very good understanding of RADAR theory. I would think as long as the magnet is not blocking line of sight for the RADAR source, it shouldn't be an issue. If directly below, this would preclude this. The metal might interfere, but the magnetic field wouldn't.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 well I’d have to add a metal plate to the bottom in order to make it attach to the magnetic base. Do you think a thin metal plate on a bottom of an R3 would be an issue?

Comment: RADAR is line of sight ... how many RADAR guns will be coming from below you?

Comment: In the UK radar speed traps are often "hidden" by the top of a hill. Putting the detector as high as possible in the car gives you a bit longer line-of-sight warning. Also if you mount the detector at dashboard level the metal of the car hood/bonnet may affect the signal strength. Why do you think driverless car prototypes have detectors mounted *on the roof*? The magnet won't affect anything just be cause it is a magnet. Anything that conducts electricity (e.g. metal) close to the line of sight between the speed trap and the detector *will* affect the signal.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 who hurt you?

Comment: @UnknownCoder - What are you hinting at? If capitalizing RADAR is what you're talking about, remember, RADAR is actually an acronym which stands for **RA**dio **D**etection **A**nd **R**anging (though I will admit, it can be used in lower case as well).